# Why doesn't my Manipulate work?

Tags: manipulate

I am new to *Mathematica* and reading my way through a few books. Playing around with `Manipulate` and I noticed the following does not work:

```
y[x_]:=x^n;
plot := Plot[y[x],{x,0,10}, AspectRatio->1];
Manipulate[plot,{n,1,5}]
```

I expected the above to work as I am using `SetDelayed` in my function definition so not sure if I understand why this doesn't work.

However the following does work.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y,x,plot},
  y[x_]:=x^n;
  plot := Plot[y[x],{x,0,10}, AspectRatio->1];
  Show[plot] 
 ],
 {n,1,5}
]
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [markdown](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page and format your question to allow for easy reading (Indenting code segments by four spaces already helps a lot).

Comment: @YvesKlett took care of it.

Comment: @rcollyer I was going for sustainable :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett I was going for quick, and a gold badge (eventually). :)

Comment: @rcollyer wuzzat? Had I but known!

Comment: @YvesKlett this [badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor). I'm a few edits shy, though.

Comment: Manipulate[Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 5}]

Comment: I didn't realise you got points and badges for editing questions. I thought everyone did it for the greater good... :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem stems from the `n` in `y[x_] := x^n;` not being in the same scope as the `n` in your `Manipulate` and, therefore, not being the same variable.

The following modified version works as you were expecting:

```
plot[n_] := Plot[x^n, {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1];
Manipulate[plot[n], {n, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that. Much appreciated.