# Using Manipulate with predefined expressions

Tags: manipulate

EDIT: I believe this is not a duplicate question, because the answers to questions pointed to as similar DO NOT give practical solutions to the problems, at least not for normal Mathematica users like me *(not computer science experts)* who are endlessly confused by the arcane details of Set, SetDelayed, Evaluate, etc.

**I thank Karsten 7 here who produced a practical, usable answer**

EDIT: in view of the questions below, in particular Bill's one, here is the puzzling code. Manipulate and the first Plot do not work, the last Plot does. Why???:

```
f[x_] = a + c x^2 + d x^3;

sol = Solve[{f[0] == f0, f[1] == f1, f'[1] == ff1, f'[0] == 0}, {a, c, d}, Reals];

g[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] := f[t] /. sol[[1]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[g[t, f0, f1, ff1], {t, 0, 1}], {{f0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{f1, 1/2}, 0, 1}, {{ff1, 0}, -1, 0}]

Plot[g[t, 0.8, 0.9, -1/2], {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[g[t, f0, f1, ff1] /. {f0 -> 0.8, f1 -> 0.9, ff1 -> -1/2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Control variables will are localized within `Manipulate`. Have a look at `Manipulate[{a, Hold[a]}, {a, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: This is very similar to your [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67277/labeling-manipulate-variables-with-their-values).

Comment: `g[t_, a_, b_] := a + b t; Manipulate[Plot[g[t, a, b], {t, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {{b, 1/2}, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @dyonis: yes it is similar, because somebody edited the previous question and deleted this part.

Comment: @Yves: can you explain ? Are you saying I should put Hold[g]?

Comment: @Bill: thanks, I know that would work, but the case I have would not be trivial to do that way

Comment: You can use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html?q=Set) (`=`) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`): `g[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] = f[t] /. sol[[1]]`

Comment: Or `Manipulate[
 Plot[g[t, f0, f1, ff1] /. {{f0 -> mf0, f1 -> mf1, ff1 -> mff1}}, {t, 0, 1}],
 {{mf0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{mf1, 1/2}, 0, 1}, {{mff1, 0}, -1, 0}]`

Comment: Thanks Karsten 7 - Set versus SetDelayed is the issue I will need to understand: please write it as an answer so I can mark it answered and vote for it

Comment: Better duplicate: [10604](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604)
(dup. [31322](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31322)).  Related: [(18820)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18820/121)

Comment: @Alberto, For people who find variable scoping an unnecessary nightmare visited upon users by CS demons, the solution `Manipulate[..., LocalizeVariables -> False]` is easier to understand and use than just about anything else. (Those to whom all variables being global is an abomination will shudder.)  HTH. :)

Comment: Thanks. The confusing thing here is that I thought I did the proper thing using g[t_, a_, b_] with the parms a,b in _(as Leonid suggests in his famous post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808))_ but in this case it was not enough, as Karsten explained

Comment: Leonid mentioned lexical scoping, which is the issue in your case, too. The explanation is that the symbols `f0` etc. do not appear in the literal (lexical), unevaluated RHS `f[t] /. sol[[1]]`. This is related to `SetDelayed` in that the substitution of the parameters is done before the RHS is evaluated. Since `t` is the only parameter appearing in the RHS, it is the only one substituted. Then the RHS is evaluated and global symbols `f0` etc. remain. `Manipulate` by default localizes symbols, so that the `f0` in it is different than the global `f0` in `g[t]`.

Comment: @Alberto, btw, I would approach this particular problem with `InterpolatingPolynomial`: `Manipulate[Plot[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0}, f0, 0}, {{1}, f1, ff1}}, t], {t, 0, 1}], {{f0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{f1, 1/2}, 0, 1}, {{ff1, 0}, -1, 0}]`.  I would have answered your related question, but the value of the interpolating polynomial sometimes exceeds `1`, violating a condition of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

The `Manipulate` and the first `Plot` of your code don't work because you use a combination of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) that doesn't behave like you expected.

When you define

```
g[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] := f[t] /. sol[[1]]
```

and now evaluate

```
g[2, 1, 1, 1]
```

you get

> ```
> f0 + 4 (-3 f0 + 3 f1 - ff1) + 8 (2 f0 - 2 f1 + ff1)
> ```

instead of the expacted

> ```
> 5
> ```

This happens because (due to the use of `:=`) `f[t]` on the rhs is first evaluated as `f[2]` (giving `a + 4 c + 8 d`) and then the replacement (`/. sol[[1]]`) is done.

## Using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`

If you replace `:=` with `=`

```
g2[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] = f[t] /. sol[[1]]
```

then `/.` will be performed only once, when you define `g2` and whenever you use `g2` it is replaced by its rhs with the `ReplacedAll` already performed.

```
g2[2, 1, 1, 1]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

## Using `Evaluate`

You can also force the evaluation of the right-hand side by using `Evaluate`:

```
g3[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] := Evaluate[f[t] /. sol[[1]]]
```

This way the rhs is evaluated before it is `SetDelayed` as the definition of `g3`.

```
Definition@g3
```

> ```
> g3[t_, f0_, f1_, ff1_] := f0 + (-3 f0 + 3 f1 - ff1) t^2 + (2 f0 - 2 f1 + ff1) t^3
> ```

## Using an additional `ReplaceAll`

You can also use an additional `/.` to replace the parameters `f0`, `f1`, and `ff1` with some values

```
g4[t_, pf0_, pf1_, pff1_] := f[t] /. sol[[1]] /. {f0 -> pf0, f1 -> pf1, ff1 -> pff1}
```

now

```
g4[2, 1, 1, 1]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

This is similar to the last `Plot` in your code.

Comment: thank you - much appreciated. I do wish Mathematica found a way to remove these kind og problems, and get closer to human/mathematical normal conventions... it keeps it from being more widely used by professionals who would like to use it, but do not have months to spend to learn the intricacies (I use it intermittently, and when I get back to it after a few weeks I loose days in solving this trivial issues.)